# Unity 3D open locally stored PDF in browser

Tags: c#, url, pdf, unity-game-engine

Unity version: 5.2.2 Building for IOS 9+.

I am having an issue where I am unable to open a pdf stored in `Applicaiton.persistentData` in the web browser via `Application.OpenURL();`

This is what I currently have:

```
Debug.Log("file://" + Application.persistentDataPath + "/WorkSmartTour/WG0047-Neighbour-Guide-TopTips_LowRes_FINAL-(2).pdf");
Application.OpenURL("file://" + Application.persistentDataPath + "/WorkSmartTour/WG0047-Neighbour-Guide-TopTips_LowRes_FINAL-(2).pdf");
```

Debug Log Output:

```
file:///Users/myname/Library/Application%20Support/Company/WorkSmart/WorkSmartTour/WG0047-Neighbour-Guide-TopTips_LowRes_FINAL-%282%29.pdf
```

If I copy and paste the debug log into the browser then the pdf opens as expected, so I am wondering if there is something I am unaware of in regards to this process.

**Additionally, please note that this application must function offline.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it because the `Application.persistentDataPath` has spaces in it perhaps?

Try using [WWW.EscapeURL()](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.EscapeURL.html)

```
Application.OpenURL("file://" + WWW.EscapeURL(Application.persistentDataPath) + "/WorkSmartTour/WG0047-Neighbour-Guide-TopTips_LowRes_FINAL-(2).pdf");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I have already ensured that it doesn't have any spaces.